# property lines of a textbox in C# using Monodevelop

Tags: c#, winforms, monodevelop

i'm writing a c# winform application in monodevelop, and i have to set the content of several lines of a multiline textbox to a specific string value using the property Lines.
So i wrote this code that in Visual studio does not generate exception and work without problem but in mono doesn't work:

```
public string[] newLines = new string[36]; 

public void Main_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      newLines[3] = "</CsOptions>";
      textBox1.Lines = newLines;
    }
```

in particular the istruction `textBox1.Lines = newLines;`give a nullreferenceexception and when i delete it, the exception expire.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete it"?

Comment: ad example set as comment with "//"

Comment: newLines or NewLines?  you've got both

Comment: newLines i have done a mistake while trascripting the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have each elements initialized to its default value. In your case, each element (which is of type `string`) is **initialized to `null`**, which is **different** from empty string `""`.

Although both .NET and mono *should* be compatible, in this particular case they are probably not. There are probably some differences in handling `TextBox.Lines` property between the two, a possible case is that mono doesn't check for `null` while .NET do.

You should avoid having `null` like that and always initialize the array. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < newLines.Length; i++){
    newLines[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: thank you Alvin, so you are telling me that i have to initialize the array to empty string and then update to the specific values those lines?